# Trunk+Etherchannel group

Tags: vlan

[image]

The problem encountered in configuring the Trunk+Etherchannel group is that PC1 and PC2 are on different network segments, but I want PC1 to be able to successfully interconnect with PC2 (ping is successful), how should I configure it?
I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please add the full switch configs to your question, using the editor's `{}` preformat option.

Comment: I don't really think the title of this question accurately represents the question.  The port-channel between the switches (and the fact that it's a trunk) does not have anything to do with making two PCs in different broadcast domains able to connect at layer-3.

Comment: Maybe this question will point you in the right direction: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80430/communication-between-different-vlans

Comment: Or this one: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28446/how-can-hosts-on-two-different-vlans-communicate

Answer (score 0):

You need a router in between to act as gateway between the 2 subnets or you need to reconfigure the 2 devices so they are on the same subnet (/22 instead of /24 or similar change) and same VLAN.

Also you left VLAN 88 out of the allowed VLAN list so whatever is in that VLAN won't pass over the trunk.

Comment: Hi FrameHowitzer :
Sorry, I am a beginner in CCNA. Could you please elaborate and guide me in more detail?By the way, I have tried to use OSPF to allow IPs in two different network segments to communicate with each other,but I want to advance to achieve Etherchannel group But encountered a bottleneck, hope to get your help, thank you.

Comment: You probably need to do more research and figure out how to do it all or just hire someone to help you because you seem to have multiple questions about basic setup and configuration. That goes beyond the nature of this site. 

If you want help configuring Etherchannel you need to post a new question about that. The configuration you have in your question appears correct and should work fine with the setup you indicated.